# "Cannot run with sound null safety" trying to use Google Maps with Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When I try running Google Maps on Android Studio Emulator I am getting an error message. It does mention some links on where to go on how to solve the problem, but I still don't get it.

The error is:

```
***

 **Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...**

***

lib\main.dart:1
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:google_maps_flutter
 - package:google_maps_flutter_platform_interface

 - package:stream_transform
 - package:plugin_platform_interface

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
3

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\14706\Desktop\CODES\Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1070

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\14706\Desktop\CODES\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 52s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

***
**Exited (sigterm)**
***
```

Comment: Check your project flutter version, and make sure to use null-safety and same goes for pub packages,

Comment: Could you include your pubspec.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in the project terminal and then run your app.

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```